# C++ linked list does not delete the head node

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a very simple node class to implement the linked list (it has only data and next pointer). The function below is supposed to delete the FIRST node that has its "data" = value.
the function works fine. But when I try to delete the first element (the head of the list), it does not. So, where is the problem?
Here is the code

```
class Node{
    public:
        int data;
        Node *next;
....some other functions...

};
void deleteNode(Node *n, int value){
    cout<<"after deleting node with data = "<<value<<" : ";
    if(n->data == value){
        n = n->next;        //I guess the problem is somewhere here!
        return;
    }
    while(n){
        if(n->next->data == value){
            n->next = n->next->next;
            return;
        }
        n = n->next;
    }
}

void printTheLinkedList(Node *n){
    while(n){
        cout<<n->data<<" --> ";
        n = n->next;
    }
    cout<<"NULL"<<endl;
}


int main(){
    Node N(0);
    for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        N.appendNode(i);

    printTheLinkedList(&N);
    deleteNode(&N, 3);
    printTheLinkedList(&N);
    deleteNode(&N, 0);
    printTheLinkedList(&N);


    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output of the code (note: 3 is deleted, but 0 is not)

```
0 --> 1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6 --> 7 --> 8 --> 9 --> NULL
0 --> 1 --> 2 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6 --> 7 --> 8 --> 9 --> NULL
0 --> 1 --> 2 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6 --> 7 --> 8 --> 9 --> NULL
```

Comment: Related: make *all* the nodes in your linked list dynamic. there is no need to keep a sentinel non-dynamic head-node. `nullptr` is a more-than-fine-enough sentinel value for deducing "list-is-empty" state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the local variable `n` to be `n->next`, the head value in `main` doesn't actually change. Try this, which returns the new head.

```
Node* deleteNode(Node *n, int value){
    cout<<"after deleting node with data = "<<value<<" : ";
    if(n->data == value){
        n = n->next;        //I guess the problem is somewhere here!
        return n;
    }
    Node* root = n;
    while(n){
        if(n->next->data == value){
            n->next = n->next->next;
            return;
        }
        n = n->next;
    }
    return root;
}
```

Then call like:

```
printTheLinkedList(&N);
Node* head = deleteNode(&N, 3);
printTheLinkedList(head);
head = deleteNode(head, 0);
printTheLinkedList(head);
```

Comment: I personally think NobuGames' answer is better, do make sure you follow his advice!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are right with your guess in your code comment. That line has to do with the issue.

There are three problems:

1. The root node cannot be deleted because it is allocated on the stack as a local variable of your `main` function.
2. The linked nodes need to be encapsulated in something like a `linked_list` container data structure. It would internally (at least) store a pointer to the `head` (e.g. beginning) of the linked list. If that `head` node gets deleted, you can just set the next pointer as the `head`
3. Your deletion code currently does not free the dynamically allocated nodes, so your app is leaking memory.

Since you're coding in C++ you could make use of smart pointers in order to take care of automatic deallocation.

Comment: +1 I concur with the smart pointer mentality, and *whole-heartedly* support its use. Care should be taken when implementing linked node systems with them, particularly when it comes to deleting them. It is not necessarily intuitive how to release such a system of nodes (such as a linked list of 100,000 items) *without* incurring a recursion into the node destructors that quickly consumes the call-activation stack to oblivion. It *is* good and right to use them, make no mistake. But doing so requires some added know-how.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for sharing your input! That scenario did not cross my mind at all but makes perfect sense. There are so many little traps to discover in C++ :-D

Comment: No problem at all. For an example of what I'm referring to, [**See it live**](http://ideone.com/DfTa0s)

Answer (score 0):

You defined head as

```
Node N(0);
```

Thus you can not delete this node (head). You should declare head as pointer to Node

```
Node *N( nullptr );
```

In this case the function can look the following way

```
void deleteNode( Node * &n, int value )
{
    cout << "after deleting node with data = " << value << " : ";

    Node *current = n;
    Node *previous = nullptr;;

    while ( current && current->data != value )
    {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    if ( current )
    {
        if ( previous ) previous->next = current->next;
        else n = nullptr;

        delete current;
    }
}
```